# Ignore other validation if one is valid C# Data Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I use Data Annotations for validating models before coming in the database. I have this 2 custom attributes:

```
[RequiredIf("OverseasResident", "Y")]
[PercentageRange]
public string Tax { get; set; }
```

The property is required only when OverseasResident = "Y" and then it checks if the property is in PercentageRange. Otherwise, it should ignore the PercentageRange.

So is there any way to ignore the PercentageRange if it isn't required?

Here are my RequiredIfAttribute and PercentageRangeAttribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _field;
    private string _expectedValue;
    public RequiredIfAttribute(string field, string expectedValue) : base("The {0} field is required if the {1} field equals {2}.")
    {
        _field = field;
        _expectedValue = expectedValue;
    }

    public override object TypeId
    {
        get { return this; }
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var propertyName = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_field);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_field) || propertyName == null) { return ValidationResult.Success; }
        var error = new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        var propertyValue = Regex.Replace(propertyName.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null).ToString().ToUpper(), @"\s+", "");
        _expectedValue = Regex.Replace(_expectedValue.ToString().ToUpper(), @"\s+", "");

        if (propertyValue == _expectedValue)
        {
            if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString())) { return error; }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        var test = validationContext.GetType();
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

PercentageRangeAttribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PercentageRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public PercentageRangeAttribute() : base("The {0} field must be in percentage range.") { }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString())) { return ValidationResult.Success; }
        bool fValid = false;

        var inputValue = Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), @"\s+", "");
        if (inputValue.IndexOf("%") == inputValue.Length - 1)
        {
            inputValue = inputValue.Replace("%", "");
        }
        var ok = decimal.TryParse(inputValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decimal parseValue);

        fValid = ok && parseValue >= 0.0m && parseValue <= 100.0m;


        if (fValid)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        } else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest that you could have `PercentageRangeAttribute` simply "succeed" if the provided value is null or empty, but it appears you already do exactly that. What's the reason that approach doesn't work for you?

Comment: @KirkLarkin If my OverseasResident != "Y", I want it to ignore the PercentageRangeAttribute because they may put some symbol there like "#####". If these symbols exist, the PercentageRange returns fail.